# Is it possible to update/insert data into dataset with SqlCommand?

Tags: asp.net, sql, dataset

I use this code to update data in database table.
Can reuse same code to update a dataset?
Thanks.

```
 using (SqlConnection cn =  new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Northwind"].ConnectionString))
        {
            string sql = "UPDATE tbh_Categories SET Title = @Title, 
                           Description = @Description 
                           WHERE CategoryID = @CategoryID";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CategoryID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = category.ID;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Title", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = category.Title;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = category.Description;

            cn.Open();
            int ret = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            return (ret == 1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no.  But, you can use [DataTable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) to identify the rows in the DataTable that you want to update.  But then you will have to modify the actual table itself "by hand".

I must ask what you are trying to do ... are you trying, for example, to cache some data using an updatable DataSet?  Or are you trying to avoid extra database trips? There may be a better way to do what you are trying to do if you let us know.  If you want an In Memory Database, there [are lots out there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database).

Per comment:  Check out [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).  There are [.NET Wrappers](http://jclement.ca/devel/dotnet/sqlite.html) that might let you do what you want.

Comment: as, i wrote in a comment above. I want to create a temporary demo of my application, without letting people actually delete and update table records.  
So for that I've decided to use dataset and keep it in session, so all manipulation would be done on this dataset (no worry about memory waste because it will be limited )

Answer (score 0):

The same exact code? No. SqlConnection (and SqlCommand) is specific to SqlServer. DataSet exists outside of that context, so you would have to rewrite your code to accomodate updating a DataSet.

Comment: I mean using SQL syntax, if it's possible then how?

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so. Either loop over the rows of your `DataTable`, or update the database and reload.

Comment: I need to store and manipulate database in memory, as demo showcase 
(I don't want people to alter my database).
So every session the data get "restored".

Answer (score 0):

You must slightly change your code. You should use an instance of [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) and use it's [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at8a576f.aspx) method. A small [code sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2.aspx) from the MSDN :

```
public DataSet CreateCmdsAndUpdate(string connectionString,
    string queryString) 
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        adapter.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
        OleDbCommandBuilder builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter);

        connection.Open();

        DataSet customers = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(customers);

        //code to modify data in dataset here

        adapter.Update(customers);

        return customers;
    }
}
```